# TCP: Read/Write POJO

Tags: java, tcp, io, pojo

I have to transfer POJOs over TCP which is connected only once. I am using the below code to send and receive the data.

```
public static void sendPacket(DataPacket packet, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    if (packet != null) {
        byte[] lenArray = new byte[2];
        byte[] data = ReadAndWriteFileUtil.serializeObject(packet);
        lenArray[0] = (byte) (data.length >>> 8);
        lenArray[1] = (byte) (data.length & 0xFF);

        byte[] serializedPacket = new byte[2 + data.length];

        System.arraycopy(lenArray, 0, serializedPacket, 0, 2);
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, serializedPacket, 2, data.length);

        System.out.println("Send Length: " + (serializedPacket.length-2));
        out.write(serializedPacket);
        //out.flush();
    }
}

public static byte[] receivePacket(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    byte[] buf = receivePacket(2, in);
    int length = ((buf[0] & 0xFF) << 8) + (buf[1] & 0xFF);

    System.out.println("Length: " + length);

    byte[] data = receivePacket(length, in);
    return data;
}

private static byte[] receivePacket(int length, InputStream in)
        throws Exception {
    int dataRec = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[length];

    while (dataRec < length) { 
        long n = in.read(data);
        if (n < 0) {
            break;
        }
        dataRec += (int) n;
    }
    if(dataRec <= 0) {
        data = null;
    }
    return data;
}
```

PROBLEM:
While sending DataPacket size = 516 bytes. But while receiving the packets, I am not able to receive only 516 bytes.

For eg: I am receiving data length as

Length: 516
Length: 516
Length: 516
Length: 516
Length: 3840
Length: 3840
Length: 516
Length: 516
Length: 516
Length: 9728
Length: 37888
Length: 42948

But each packet should be of length 516.

What am I doing wrong. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should **not** be reading separate packets at all, just write and read objects. Allow Java `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to do their job

Comment: @Germann Using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream add size overhead for the Object. I am working on a time-efficient file transfer method where I need separate packets to be transferred.

Comment: AFAIR you can still provide custom serialization/de-serialization and avoid size overhead by doing that.